# How does program decides the encoding of the xml file?

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8

I am having a doubt on xml encoding while processing(Unmarshall) the xml file.
We specify the encoding of the xml file in in the start of the file as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

My question is after program reads this line, it decides the following content is encoded in UTF-8. But to read this first line, how does the program decides it is encoded in UTF-8? I mean while reading the byte stream, how does program knows that it need to use which encoding for first line?

Regards,
Mayuran

Answer (score 2):

It is written in section F.1. of the xml specification:

> F.1 Detection Without External Encoding Information
>
> Because each XML entity not accompanied by external encoding
>   information and not in UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding must begin with an XML
>   encoding declaration, in which the first characters must be `<?xml`,
>   any conforming processor can detect, after two to four octets of
>   input, which of the following cases apply. In reading this list, it
>   may help to know that in `UCS-4`, `<` is `#x0000003C` and `?` is 
>   `#x0000003F`, and the Byte Order Mark required of `UTF-16` data streams is `#xFEFF`. The notation ## is used to denote any byte value except
>   that two consecutive ##s cannot be both 00.

Basically, there are two options:

1. There is a Byte-order-mark (BOM)
2. There is no BOM.

The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-guessing-no-ext-info) then clearly documents tables of specific octet streams that the processor should use to determine the encoding to use up-through seeing the `encoding` declaration.

Comment: **There** it is. I was looking through the spec, knew it was there, but didn't quite get down to F.1 before you posted the above. Nice one.

Comment: @RobAu, Thanks for the answer, but i still not able to understand, to read the text "<?xml" it must first decide the encoding no? Without deciding the encoding, how does it know it is "<?xml". I believe with UTF-8 encoding only it is "<?xml". If we use some other encoding it may be interpreted as different character set. Just my thought only. Please clear me if i am wrong.

Comment: If there is no byte order mark you should read the first few bytes and try the different encodings, like UTF-16. The encoding that gives the string '<?xml' is the one you should use to read the rest of the line.

Comment: Technically appendix F is non-normative; XML doesn't actually define processing without external encoding metadata, rather just, uh, saying how one can.